# spring boot Dao test

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, junit

i have a test case for dao implementation.
Test Class Code -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest({XyzDaoImpl.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class XyzDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    XyzDaoImpl xyzDaoImpl;

    @Test
    public void testGetXyzDetails(){
        assertThat(xyzDaoImpl.getXyzDetails("123", null)).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

xyzDaoImpl.getXyzDetails method implementation calls a backend using RestTemplate.
This test works fine when my config class code contains -

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

but if i create the rest template using builder to set timeout etc , Test fails -

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
            .build();
}
```

Tried creating Bean using @Profile("test") default and @Profile("!test") - custom setting, still test fails.
Error is -

```
 testException = java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP POST http://... url.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running with `@RestClientTest`,  `RestTemplate` returned from `RestTemplateBuilder` are not real clients.  They are connected to a fake server( `MockRestServiceServer`), which needs to be setup with expected requests and their corresponding responses.

The previous test with `new RestTemplate()` is an actual client that talks to a network.

If you want `RestTemplateBuilder` to generate a `RestTemplate` to talk to a real server, you can take off `@RestClientTest`.

If you want `RestTemplateBuilder` to generate a mocked `RestTemplate` that talks to a `MockRestServiceServer`,

- Use `@RestClientTest`
- Setup the `MockRestServiceServer`
- Use `RestTemplateBuilder` to generate a `RestTemplate`, and send the requests configured in the previous step.

As follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest({XyzDaoImpl.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class XyzDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {             
            this.server.expect(requestTo("/...url"))
              .andRespond(withSuccess("{\"status\": \"ok\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetXyzDetails(){
        assertThat(xyzDaoImpl.getXyzDetails("123", null)).isNotNull();
    }
}

class XYZDaoImpl {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate client;
    String getXyzDetails(String a, String b) {
        return client.getForObject("/...url", String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing @RestClientTest took care of this. Thanks

Comment: When i keep @RunClientTest like above for unit test, i am getting unable to load applicationContext error.<br>Change i did was adding  below in setup method<br>server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(new RestTemplate());<br>Also tried including classes that are Autoried in XYZDaoImpl. After adding EnabledWebMvc i get no bean java.servlet.ServletContext

Comment: `ServletContext` is provided by @WebAppConfiguration.  It's trying to find one because you have a component with @EnableWebMvc in your component scan path.  You can either exclude the component with @EnableWebMvc or add another that has a @WebAppConfiguration.